# Using Skype4Com under IIS7

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, skype4com

I have a problem working with Skype4Com under IIS7. The code is simple:

```
Skype skype = new Skype();
skype.Attach();

Command cmd = new Command();
cmd.Command = "CHATMESSAGE #chatname/someid test";
skype.SendCommand(cmd);
```

It works if executed as a console app or from aspx page under IISExpress but doesn't work if the page runs under normal IIS 7.

I'm setting **Enable 32-bit applications** to true, i'm setting **Identity** for the pool to my current user account. I'm even used **WindowsImpersonationContext** and executed the code within the context but nothing helps:

call

```
skype.Attach();
```

Fails with error

> Wait timeout

I saw a couple of similar issues posted here and there orver the internet but found no solution. Have anybody experiences the same problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you running this code on a shared webhost? They might be blocking all outbound connections.